# How to kill container generated by docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

(sorry using the term "kill" with quotes is not about `docker-compose kill`, is about "UNIX `ps` kill" after what the process really go out of the "UNIX `ps` list")

---

Usual `docker run` can be "killed" by usual `docker stop`, because after stop I not see the container at `docker ps -a`... If it is correct, there are a semantic bug with `docker-compose`  because I can't "kill" the containers, they stay at `docker ps`.

After my simple `docker-compose up` (without `&`) I do `^C`  and the containers stay there at `docker ps -a`... Impossible to kill by `docker compose stop`.

---

NOTE: when I use ordinary `docker run` and after it `docker stop` there are nothing at `docker ps -a`, so I can say "I killed it".

Comment: Plase comment your close vote, I used the term "kill" **with quotes** since the first post and all edits.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Usual `docker run` can be "killed" by usual `docker stop`, because after stop I not see the container at `docker ps`.

No. `docker stop` just stops a running container, it doesn' t remove the container. This happens only in case you've used `docker run --rm ...`. This `--rm` option means that when the container is stopped, it will be removed/deleted.

---

## Docker

- `docker run ...` creates and runs a container
- `docker stop ...` stops a running container
- `docker start ...` starts a stopped container
- `docker rm ...` removes a stopped container

---

## Docker Compose

- `docker-compose up` creates and runs a **collection** of containers
- `docker-compose stop` stops the containers
- `docker-compose start` starts the containers
- `docker-compose down` **stops and removes the containers** 
  (this is the answer for the question)

---

## Be careful...

As it discussed in the comments section, by using `docker-compose down` other things can also take place regarding `volumes`, `networks`. Keep in mind that you might lose data (if your container is a database for example) and make sure you have saved them or you are somehow able to create them again.

Comment: Perfect, `docker-compose down` is the magic to really "kill" the container! But sorry, my dummy experience with `docker stop`  **was different**  (and was with many cases), no `docker ps -a` stay there.

Comment: Be carefull with `docker-compose down` command, it will remove all volumes attached to your containers. For example in a database container, when you execute that command, it will destroy all persistent data.

Comment: Thanks!  Only to future dummy readers: please edit to enhance/bold the answer, it is `docker-compose down`.

Comment: @AntoineAmara Amara  Sorry but that's wrong. `docker-compose down` *does not* remove named volumes. From the `docker-compose down --help`:

By default, the only things removed are:

- Containers for services defined in the Compose file
- Networks defined in the `networks` section of the Compose file
- The default network, if one is used

You can add the -v option to force removing volumes.

Comment: I edited question-text to `ps -a`, with the used option at *"... after stop I not see the container at `docker ps -a`..."*; and yes, it is a database-like service. @Alkaline thanks the complete explanation and tip about `-v` option.

Comment: Oh yes right @Alkaline , `external volumes` are not removed but I think `anonymous volume` and internal datas are destroyed.

Answer (score 7):

Check out running containers:

`docker ps`

Example output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
e86521d81a96        app_php                 "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 hours ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp               app_php_1
7a30681b6255        mysql:5.6               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp             app_db_1
21aa3eef5f42        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/run.sh supervisord…"   4 hours ago         Up About an hour    9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp     app_phpmyadmin_1
9afc52b3f82f        mailhog/mailhog         "MailHog"                4 hours ago         Up About an hour    1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8082->8025/tcp   app_mailhog_1
```

then stop one by the container id:

`docker kill part_of_the_id/name`

For instance:

`docker kill e86` or `docker kill app_php_1`

Docker-compose is just a script to help you manage one or multiple containers running in a group and is absolutely not required to manage your containers.

To remove the container completely you have to remove the container `docker rm container_id_or_name`

To gracefully stop all running containers:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
```

To kill all running containers:

```
docker kill -s9 $(docker ps q)
```

Comment: Yes,  I described, I do it, and they are at `docker ps -a`, **not kill**

Comment: `docker ps -a` lists stopped containers as well. So what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: "to kill", because when I do it with "usual `docker`" they are "killed"

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `docker rm <container-name>` to do that. This command will stop and remove service container. Anonymous volumes attached to the container will not be removed.

Comment: Hum...  good clue (!), but `docker-compose rm 02bba17004e2` generated "ERROR: No such service: 02bba17004e2"

Comment: I'm sorry that's a mistake the command is `docker rm` , I supposed you used `docker-compose` to run your containers.